# find distinct count conditionally

Tags: sql, postgresql

With a table `table1` as below which tracks movement of cars from a renting station

```
+---------+---------+----------+--------+------+-------+-------+--------+
| station |   make  |   model  |  start |  end |  kms  |  time |  regno |
+---------+---------+----------+--------+------+-------+-------+--------+
|    1111 |  toyota |  camry   |  ca    |  mh  |  1200 |    12 |   2222 |
|    1111 |  toyota |  camry   |  ca    |  mg  |  1300 |    14 |   2233 |
|    1111 |  honda  |  accord  |  ab    |  mx  |  1400 |    12 |   2255 |
|    1111 |  honda  |  accord  |  ab    |  mx  |  1400 |    12 |   2255 |
|    1122 |  toyota |  corolla |  ab    |  mg  |   800 |     8 |   2244 |
|    1133 |  honda  |  accord  |  ab    |  mx  |   900 |     7 |   2255 |
|    1133 |  honda  |  accord  |  ab    |  mx  |   900 |     7 |   2277 |
+---------+---------+----------+--------+------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Need to find the distinct cars ( by `regno`) for each station, distinct cars with make `honda` and `non-honda` as in the expected output below

```
+---------+----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
| station |  distinct_cars_count |  make_honda_distinct_cnt |  make_non_honda_distinct_cnt |
+---------+----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|    1111 |                    3 |                        1 |                            2 |
|    1122 |                    1 |                        0 |                            1 |
|    1133 |                    2 |                        2 |                            0 |
+---------+----------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------+
```

I could find the distinct cars as below

```
select
 count(distinct regno) as distinct_cars_count 
from table1
group by station
```

I need help with finding `make_honda_distinct_cnt` which is distinct cars with `make = 'honda'` and `make_non_honda_distinct_cnt` which would be distinct cars with `make <> 'honda'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement inside the count:

```
select  station,
        count(distinct regno) as distinct_cars_count,
        count(distinct case when make = 'honda' then regno end) as make_honda_distinct_cnt,
        count(distinct case when make <> 'honda' then regno end) as make_non_honda_distinct_cnt,
from    table1
group by station
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use conditional aggregation using a `filter()` clause:

```
select count(distinct regno) as distinct_cars_count , 
       count(distinct regno) filter (where make = 'honda') as make_honda_distinct_cnt, 
       count(distinct regno) filter (where make <> 'honda') as make_non_honda_distinct_cnt
from table1
group by station
```